# Finding GUI elements with pywinauto

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

I am trying my first things with pywinauto.
Now I want to make use of `print_control_identifiers()` but I get errors, however I write my code - I cant get any information about GUI objects.
I already tried to generate the code via [swapy](https://code.google.com/p/swapy/downloads/detail?name=swapy-ob-0.4.3.exe&can=2&q=) - had a lot of generated code, but no success.

This is my code so far:

```
import getpass, fnmatch

from pywinauto import application

currentUser = getpass.getuser()

if fnmatch.fnmatch(currentUser, "axe"):
    pwa_app = application.Application()
    w_handle = application.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Login - 0.9.347', class_name='WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r11_ad1')[0]
    window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
    window.SetFocus()
    ctrl = window['Log In']
    ctrl.Click()


else:
    print "You need admin rights for that action"
```

Can you tell me, where I need to use `print_control_identifiers()`?
Do you have any other GUI automation frameworks that are more up-to-date?

Comment: What is the script output?
pywinauto can work with many Windows Forms controls.

Comment: Why don't you use `pwa_app = application.Application().connect_(path='your.exe)`? find_windows is supposed as internal staff. `pwa_app.Window_(title=u'Login - 0.9.347', class_name='...')` returns almost the same WindowSpecification object.

Answer (score 1):

PrintControlIdentifiers() is useful for top level window. If `window` is top level window specification, then just call

```
window.PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

or

```
 pwa_app.Window_(title=u'Login - 0.9.347', top_level_only=True).PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few examples:

Swapy is good to identify the properties. Also, the examples given with pywinauto are quite helpful.
Source: https://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/getting_started.html

```
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application.Start("Notepad.exe")
app.Notepad.print_control_identifiers()
app.Notepad.MenuSelect("Edit->Replace")
app.Replace.print_control_identifiers()
```

from pywinauto import application

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application()
app.Start("Notepad.exe")
Wnd_Main = app.window_(title_re=".*Notepad")
Wnd_Main.MenuSelect("File->Save")

Wnd_Save = app.window_(title_re="Save As")
Wnd_Save.Edit1.SetEditText("Hello World.txt")
```